# Add custom Apache config. rules for subdirectory within the same <Directory ...> section?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, httpd.conf

Say my Apache configuration file '/etc/apache2/httpd.conf' looks like this (I don't use .htaccess):

```
<Directory /var/www/whatthenerd.com/public>
    AllowOverride None

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        [...]
    </IfModule>

    [...]
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/whatthenerd.com/public/uploads/css>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /uploads/css/

        [...]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Considering that `/var/www/whatthenerd.com/public/uploads/css` is a sub-directory of `/var/www/whatthenerd.com/public`, I believe I can merge the rules. But somehow, I am unable to get it to work.

I am not sure what's wrong with this, and why it isn't working...

```
<Directory /var/www/whatthenerd.com/public>
    AllowOverride None

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        [...]
    </IfModule>

    [...]

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteBase /uploads/css/

        [...]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "no, you can't, because it doesn't work that way". You can't have two RewriteBase within the same Directory context.

Comment: In that case, would it be possible for you to tell me what's wrong with this? http://serverfault.com/a/540990/102450 The answer used to work, but now, it doesn't, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: "doesn't work" is insufficient data to give any useful answer. Start by turning on logging and reading the rewrite logs.

Comment: **Note to self:** Nevermind, they weren't working because the `Include httpd.conf` directive was missing in apache's main configuration file, i.e. /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.